# running shell script from php

Tags: php, macos, shell, babeljs

I have a shell script which works perfectly if I run it in the terminal (MAC OSX)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chemedit/

babel -imol  'a.mol' -oinchi 'outputfile.inchi'
babel -imol  'a.mol' -osmi 'a.smsi'
babel a.smi -O out.svg  -xC -xe
exit
```

I have this in a file called a.sh

I want to run this from PHP using:

> $output = shell_exec("bash a.sh 2>&1");

This does not work and returns:

```
  Cannot write to outputfile.inchi
0 molecules converted
1 errors
```

for all files

- I have given both files chmod 777.
- I am pretty sure safe mode is off for PHP.

Comment: add babel's path to the script.

Comment: which shell and user is `shell_exec` using with your PHP configuration? Which shell and user are you using when you run it in your terminal? Do both configurations differ? If yes, in which points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling babel with its absolute name. Use `which babel` to determine this, and replace 'babel' with it in your script.

Comment: thanks i seem to be getting somewhere now i get a Cannot write to a.smsi error im guessing this has somthing to do with permissions

Comment: Thankyou so much you've helped me so much

Answer (score 2):

The `babel` command is likely not in the `PATH` environment variable for the user running PHP, and thus the script via PHP.  The simplest solution is to edit your shell script to refer to babel by its full path.

Comment: thanks i seem to be getting somewhere now i get a   Cannot write to a.smsi error im guessing this has somthing to do with permissions